# I have one column with multiple categories like a,b,c and other column with corresponding numbers to a,b,c , How can we calculate median

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table containing columns like category and values

I want to find the median of individual category I tried the "=median and if formula", it is working if I have two categories only if I have 3 like below data it does work, I want to do this without using pivot table actually that's a constrain

| Categories | Values |
| --- | --- |
| a | 5 |
| b | 4 |
| c | 9 |
| c | 10 |
| b | 6 |
| a | 2 |
| c | 11 |
| b | 7 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 8 |

I tried to formulate my requirement on the table but I guess there is some problem with the formula here

=IF(A2:A11="a",MEDIAN(B2:B11),IF(A2:A11="b",MEDIAN(B2:B11),IF(A2:A11="c",MEDIAN(B2:B11))))

Apart from this I tried the pivot table as well by using add measure it worked but I don't know why is it not working through formula

Answer (score 3):

[image: Result-1]

if you want to drag the formula then take unique categories and apply the formula.. in **F2** cell

=MEDIAN(IF($B$2:$B$11=E2,$C$2:$C$11,""))

Answer (score 2):

Your condition part of the if statement is returning an array.  Don't use IF()...

You need to filter the column A.

```
=MEDIAN(FILTER(B1:B11,A1:A11="a"))
=MEDIAN(FILTER(B1:B11,A1:A11="b"))
=MEDIAN(FILTER(B1:B11,A1:A11="c"))
```

Comment: Hey that is great. Please checkmark the answer, and if you like it you can also upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following formula for spill down array. You do not need to drag down, no need to put formula to individual cells.

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:A11),y,MAP(x,LAMBDA(a,MEDIAN(FILTER(B2:B11,A2:A11=a)))),HSTACK(x,y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a Pivot Table, along with the build-in (Excel-2013 and higher) Power Pivot option to include your own measure:

- Select your data, and in the 'Insert' tab, click 'Pivot Table' in the 'Tables' group;
- Make sure to tick the 'Add this data to the Data Model' option and hit 'OK';
- Then go to the 'Power Pivot' tab, (or [enable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/start-the-power-pivot-add-in-for-excel-a891a66d-36e3-43fc-81e8-fc4798f39ea8) it first if you haven't). Under the 'Calculations' group, click 'Measures' and choose to add a new one;
- Choose an appropriate 'Measure name:' and use the following formula: `=MEDIAN([Values])`;
- The Pivot Table should be selected, just click 'Categories' which will auto-populate the labels.

[image]